# Javascript Return Value without breaking loop

Tags: javascript, parse.js

My code is currently as follows. I'm using the Parse.Js library.

```
while (i < workout) {

    return q.find({
        success: function (type) {
            if (type == 3) {
                typeCount++;
            }
        }
    });
    i++;
}
```

The problem is the 'return' seems to stop the rest of the function from working. Is there a way to do this without breaking the loop?

I tried removing the return all together but then the q.find code doesn't run.

Comment: Then don't `return`...

Comment: And what is this `.find` method?

Comment: assign the result to a variable, return it after the while

Comment: @Matheus I was thinking that, but it seems like this mysterious `find` method is asynchronous (not sure, I'm just thinking of what `success` normally means in jQuery at least)

Comment: And no comments from OP.. We are trying to guess and he is probably drinking tee and watching the TV show now..

Comment: The find method is part of the parse framework. https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries (no not drinking tea was taking a crap) I remove return and the find function doesn't run.

Comment: @PhilipK Maybe include that in your question next time, as it isn't apparent with just the `parsing` tag. Also, you may want to include more of your code as a context for us trying to help. We have no idea what else happens in your function, how it's being called, or what exactly you want this function to do anyways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `return` ends execution of the function, breaking all loops, `if` blocks, etc. You can store the value in a variable and return that at the end (once your loops are finished), but `return` stops the function.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't, instead of 'return' you could add the values to an array and then return that array.